# Retracting an edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

I just realized that I submitted an edit request when entirely too tired to sanely do so, and accidentally sent an incorrect title correction, and realized that there’s no way to retract it.

However, I think it would be nice to either be able to cancel/retract a sent edit suggestion, showing that you know that it was wrong and thus not needing anyone to look over it, or add a way to comment on an edit suggestion so that you can make the reviewers aware of the error.

Comment: See: [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/145982)

Comment: @kyrias I've experienced an similar situation, thanks for the question.

Comment: Normally, reviewers are expected to, well, review your edit, and consider if it's valid. They can also fix your mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have rejected your edit so no harm done. In my opinion, this is not something that happens often enough to merit a feature. Next time, just pop into the main site's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) and ask someone there to reject your edit.

If there's no one around, you can also flag the post with a custom flag and tell us (the mods) what happened. We'll deal with it.

Thanks for posting here, you're clearly trying to do the right thing and that's appreciated. Don't worry about it though, we all make mistakes.